# In the Node js How to restrict the user login attempts individually?

Tags: node.js, express, express-rate-limit

I'm using express-rate-limit for limiting the API access using this code

```js
 const limiter = limtter({
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hrs in milliseconds
    max: 5,
    message: {
      code: 429,
      message: "You have exceeded the 5 requests in 1-hour limit!",
    },
    standardHeaders: true,
    legacyHeaders: false,
  });
```

But it is applied to all requests of API affecting all the users once the limit is crossed. How to add limit for the particular user?

Comment: Seems like you are using proxy because `express-rate-limit` library is using client ip to identify as a separate request, if you are using proxy then you may use `app.set('trust proxy', 1)`

Comment: I included this. It works fine for different IPs. If you use a different browser in the same system you access login API. How to make it more secure by using only default memory storage?